# How to set rockemq message expired time?

Tags: spring-cloud, rocketmq

Here I am using spring-cloud-starter-stream-rocketmq and spring-message to send message dn,
e.g.

```
Message m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(obj).setHeader(RocketMQHeaders.TAGS, tag).build();
MessageChannel.output().send(m);
```

But I want to set the message expire time in the queue if that not be consumed.

I know the rocketmq could set the ttl, but I don't know whether that can be set for different message and how can be used in the code before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you are wrong.

RocketMQ does not support ttl which means the message will NOT be deleted controlled by a client parameter, though the message will be indeed deleted after a period of time(for example 7 days).

So if you need to implement a ttl like consuming, you should do it in your consumer like:

```
  if (System.currentTimeMills()-msg.getStoreTimestamp > SOME_TIME) {
     //DO NOT CONSUME
  }
```